# DC-DC converter fault output

Tags: integrated-circuit, dc-dc-converter, debugging, troubleshooting

We have a design using 4 EM2130L02QI dc/dc converter all with very similar routing and component placement. the output gets shorted to GND and never changed . the same board that contain with another assembly batch was working.

We have used this regulator in multiple projects and it works the only change is the PCB assembly house and this is the first time we have seen such an issue !

Is there someone who can help us debug this issue ?

attaching the waveform output:

Input voltage : 12V(PVIN)

VCC:5V

CTRL/ENABLE=3.3V
[image]

you can see clearly that VOUT EVEN DOESNT CHANGE!

layout:
[image: LAYOUT:]

SCHEMATIC:
[image]

**EDIT:**
We ask from assembly house to perform X-RAY to DC/DC, its very hard to say if something wrong with soldering ( there are short circuit between pads because its required) these the results:
[image]
[image]
[image]

It's hard for me to say the quality of the soldering I would like to hear some advice from you
thanks.

Comment: "the only change is the PCB assembly house" - do they guarantee the same specs as the original fab?

Comment: they better than the previous..  there is any difference in date-code of the new dc/dc compare as the previous

Comment: Don't just stare at your computer tools. Go and get the actual broken circuit and figure out what's wrong with it. You can de-solder the components: do the pads have continuity where you expect? Are the components the right ones? Do they work?

Comment: It's not like software, where you make a change and it stops working and all the internals can be hidden from you. No, you have an *actual circuit* in front of you, two of them, and one works and one doesn't, and there must be something different between them. The cause is not "we changed assembly house", the cause is that the new assembly house is doing *something* differently.

Comment: @user253751 the assembly house just bought the ICS and solder them into the board, I told you that the date-code different(of each DC/DC converter) maybe there is options for Fake devices? the PCB is the same we just brought it to another assembly house , the voltage tested in the input of  the IC , what going inside I cant tell

Comment: @user253751 we even compare resistance of each resistor one by one of the two circuits, no change, same resistance.

Comment: @Knowledge Okay, resistors are all fine, but resistors are just about the least likely thing to be the problem here. Are you certain every pad of the converter is soldered and making good contact to the PCB? Are all the capacitors fine? Also, please upload higher resolution images of the layout and especially the schematic; these are unreadable.

Comment: @Hearth the schematic doesn't matter because it has the same components in the same PCB. the PCBs are the same and the difference is the assembly, how can I check the pad of the converter? this is BGA and very difficult to touch underneatch

Comment: @Knowledge The schematic helps a lot to look at what *could* be causing the problem; it absolutely does matter. Usual process for checking BGAs is to x-ray them, but this isn't a BGA, it's a QFN. You should be able to see most of the pads with just a microscope.

Comment: @Hearth PLEASE LOOK AT THE NEW UPDATE

Comment: Just feed the shorted output with an external current source (e.g. 2V@5A) and watch the current path with an infrared camera. In many cases this directly shows you the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> the only change is the PCB assembly house ...

> the assembly house just bought the ICS and solder them into the board

I have just checked the EM2130L02QI IC and seen that it's [obsolete](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/intel/EM2130L02QI/7380341) since January this year. This means that the IC is no longer in production. I don't know when you gave the production order but there's always a small chance that the IC can be fake. But it's highly likely that the ICs might have been purchased months before the IC became obsolete. Nevertheless, extra care must be taken when using an obsolete IC in a recent production, especially when you are not the ones who purchased the ICs. I say again: I'm not saying that the IC is fake but still it's worth to check.

A few words about the assembly process:

- There's no data given in the datasheet about soldering and assembly process. Let's hope the assembly house didn't apply random heating process. Remember that some components may get damaged during reflow soldering.
- Let's hope the employees used proper ESD protection equipment during assembly and packaging.
- Let's hope the assembly house ran 100% visual check to every board. In some cases you may want them to make some initial test(s) to the boards. This may help to take precautions by raising a red flag before a batch assembly run.

What you can do at the moment is to make some measurements on both working and broken boards and compare them. For example, check if the output terminals of the IC is shorted to ground when no input voltage is applied.

Comment: Hi , we make some me measurements on both working and broken board and the outputs shorted to ground - this is something that supposed to be. this assembly house considered better and better quality. 
all the board with the same problem the only difference as I said its the date code is different so I hope its not fake.